# 2sxc: In-Page Editing with QuickE

Tags: 2sxc

Using 2sxc 8.8 for DNN Evoq Content 8.3, and in-page editing with QuickE is not working. I've enabled quick edit on all pages but still have to enter the "Edit" mode in order to see the module I have just added using the "Add to content" button. Also tested the "Empty Pane" issue and still not working. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots to clarify?

Comment: Here's a screencast of what the issue is: [link](http://recordit.co/g4zq2zvTHC).You can see that when I click on the "Add to content" button the page refreshes but the module is not visible. Once I enter "Edit" mode the module is now ready for use. Please advise. Thanks. @iJungleBoy

Comment: Great movie - that helps. Question: do you have a workflow with "direct publish" or with some kind of verification? The behaviour seems to indicate that the view-mode hides the module till you publish it. Could this be the initial cause?

Comment: Yes, the Default Page Workflow is Direct Publish. Is that causing the issue? If it is, how do I fix it? @iJungleBoy

Comment: Direct-Publish sounds like a no-problems situation, like it should just work. Can you do a few checks: do you have JS errors, is the dnn-module-wrapper on the page but just without the content, or is the wrapper even missing? Since you had to press "publish", it doesn't sound like a directpublish - can you verify that?

Comment: There are no JS errors. The “dnn-module-wrapper” (if I understand correctly, a set of 2sxc module-specific <div> tags surrounding module contents)  is not present on the page after a module instance was added via QuickE toolbar’s “Add content to…” , but If you enter into “Page Edit” mode they become visible and available for further manipulation. It has a “Direct Publish” workflow and it’s a “Default Page Workflow” set for the site in Workflow Management (Admin > Workflow Management).

Comment: We'll try to look into it. Pls open issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

We did some research and at the moment this appears to be happening:

1. Evoq creates a new "page version" as the module is added, marking this page-version as draft
2. The preview still shows the "public version" - and hides the new module. This also seems to be the case for moving a module - which creates a new version
3. Since evoq believes that all changes happen in the edit-mode, it doesn't present a publish-button (which would make the new "page version" public) and hides all module move/add changes in the preview

We are working on a solution and continuing this discussion here: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1103

Comment: Thanks for looking this issue. It's much appreciated. @iJungleBoy